# While creating Horizontal BarChart my positive values(Text) are showing outside the bars but negative are showing inside the bars

Tags: android, kotlin

bars are created but dont know why positive values are showing outside the bars but neagtive values are showing inside the bars

fun setGraph(
horizontalBarChart: HorizontalBarChart,
model: ResModel,
index: Int,
currentMonth: Int
) {
val list = model.revenue?.sale

```
    if (list  != null) {
        initHorizontalBarChart(horizontalBarChart)
        val barWidth = 0.32f

        val currentSale = ArrayList<BarEntry>()
        val monthsList = ArrayList<String>()

        for (i in index..currentMonth) {
            currentSale .add(
                BarEntry(
                    i.toFloat(),
                    list.actual[i].currentSale,
                    list.actual[i].currentSale
                )
            )
            monthsList.add(list.actual[i].month)
        }
        val font = ResourcesCompat.getFont(horizontalBarChart.context, R.font.poppins_semi_bold)

        val xAxis = horizontalBarChart.xAxis
        xAxis.granularity = 1f
        xAxis.isGranularityEnabled = true
        xAxis.labelCount = monthsList.size
        xAxis.textSize = 12f
        xAxis.typeface = font
        xAxis.axisMinimum = -0.5f
        xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(false)
        xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(monthsList)
        xAxis.position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM

        val leftAxis: YAxis = horizontalBarChart.axisLeft
        leftAxis.setLabelCount(list.splitCounter.toInt(), true)
        leftAxis.textSize = 10f
        leftAxis.typeface = font
        leftAxis.gridColor = Color.rgb(211, 213, 214)
        leftAxis.enableGridDashedLine(10f, 10f, 10f)

        val barDataSet = BarDataSet(currentSale, "Current")
        barDataSet.color = Color.rgb(255, 208, 39)    //yellow

        val data = BarData(barDataSet)
        horizontalBarChart.data = data
        horizontalBarChart.isDragEnabled = true
        horizontalBarChart.barData.setValueTypeface(font)
        data.isHighlightEnabled = false
        horizontalBarChart.setVisibleXRange(3f, 3f)
        data.setDrawValues(true)
        horizontalBarChart.xAxis.axisMinimum = -0.5f
        horizontalBarChart.barData.setValueTextSize(9f)
        data.barWidth = barWidth
        horizontalBarChart.setScaleEnabled(false)
        horizontalBarChart.extraBottomOffset = 10f
        horizontalBarChart.barData.setValueFormatter(object : ValueFormatter() {
            override fun getBarLabel(barEntry: BarEntry?): String {
                return barEntry?.data.toString()
            }
        })
        horizontalBarChart.invalidate()
        horizontalBarChart.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

}
```

i want to show negative values outside the bars